# filtering data from redux store using useSelector?

Tags: reactjs, react-native

I have an array that is stored in the store and I want to access a specific item in that array.

My question is this implementation practical ?
Or is there a better way to find that specific item in the array in redux ??

```
const category = useSelector((state) =>
    state?.user?.userData?.businessInfo?.categories?.find(
      (item) => item.name === type
    )
  );
```

Answer (score 0):

Would you please add the reducer to better understand the problem ;
otherwise, you should access the reducer by useSelector and affect that array into the const category ;

```
const categories =useSelector((state) => state.user.userData.businessInfo )
//and then 
const category = categories.find((item) => item.name === type)
```